# ActivityBinding Does Not Work For Preference Pages

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

The use case is the following: We have a lot preference pages, but depending on what user is logged in, only a couple of the pages are shown. We used activity bindings to realize that:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity id="org.acme.user.isAdmin" name="Admin Activity">
        <enabledWhen>
            <test property="org.acme.user.userName" value="ADMIN" />
        </enabledWhen>
    </activity>
    <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="org.acme.user.isAdmin"
        isEqualityPattern="true"
        pattern="org.acme.project/org.acme.project.MyPreferencePage">
    </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
    <propertyTester
        class="org.acme.user.UserTester"
        id="org.acme.user.UserTester"
        namespace="org.acme.user"
        properties="userName"
        type="java.lang.Object">
    </propertyTester>
 </extension>
```

There are a couple more, of course. Now this setup works fine if we log in as one of the users. If we logout and re-login, the preference pages shown are according to the following pattern:

- if the first user was able to see the page, it's visibility is calculated correctly
- if the first user was not able to see the page, the second user is not either

Since the property tester is doing its job, and everything works for the first login, I assume the problem lies with how the preference dialog creates its pages. In fact, the following line will always print the same number over the course of an application, no matter how many pages are visible:

```
System.out.println(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager().getRootSubNodes().length);
```

(I get that it doesn't go down, because there's a cache for the pages. But it should go **up** when the activity binding suddenly decides the page should be visible.)

Can anybody shed light on what might trigger these problems, and how we can fix them? (we're using Eclipse 3.7)

Comment: It looks to me like filtering is done when the pages are read from the extension point registry (by PreferencePageRegistryReader) but nothing is set up to respond to any changes to enabled activities later on.

Comment: Looks like this is probably the (very old) bug [65352](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=65352)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can be used to register all pages at the `PreferenceManager`:

```
    // get the pages from the registry
    PreferencePageRegistryReader registryReader = new PreferencePageRegistryReader(PlatformUI.getWorkbench());
    registryReader.loadFromRegistry(Platform.getExtensionRegistry());

    // we get the unfiltered list of pages
    Field topLevelNodes = CategorizedPageRegistryReader.class.getDeclaredField("topLevelNodes"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    topLevelNodes.setAccessible(true);
    Collection<?> pageContributions = (Collection<?>) topLevelNodes.get(registryReader);
    topLevelNodes.setAccessible(false);

    // we remove the ones already displayed
    Set<String> alreadyDisplayedIds = (Set<String>) registryReader.getTopLevelNodes().stream()
            .filter(o -> o instanceof WorkbenchPreferenceNode).map(n -> ((WorkbenchPreferenceNode) n).getId())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    for (Iterator<?> iterator = pageContributions.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Object object = iterator.next();
        if (object instanceof WorkbenchPreferenceNode
                && alreadyDisplayedIds.contains(((WorkbenchPreferenceNode) object).getId())) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    // now we add the currently invisible pages
    ((WorkbenchPreferenceManager) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager()).addPages(pageContributions);
```

Still that leaves the problem that evidently the preference dialog isn't able to handle activity binding changes, so half the time you can see the preferences change right before your eyes when opening the dialog... and half the time the dialog doesn't react to the changes at all.